# Migrating old table to new table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, optimization, pivot

I have a problem where i need to migrate old table to new table. The old table data example like this:

**Old table**(Leave table)

Id   User_id    Reason    Date
1    100          Fever      29/01/2013
2    100          Fever      30/01/2013
3    100          Fever      31/01/2013
4    100          Fever      01/02/2013

**New table**(Leave table)

Id   User_id    Reason    Start Date   End Date
1    100          Fever      29/01/2013   01/02/2013

Is there any way where i can iterate old table and store like new table.?

29/01/2013 - 01/02/2013 produce 4 rows.. new table need 1 rows which start date and end date which 29/01/2013 be the start date and 01/02/2013 be the end date

new table i already created. i just want to iterate the list of old table and insert it into new table which have start date and end date.

Comment: date column going to what start date or enddate or both or none ?

Comment: 29/01/2013 - 01/02/2013 produce 4 rows.. new table need 1 rows which start date and end date which 29/01/2013 be the start date and 01/02/2013 be the end date

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the `Date` column to `Start Date` and add a new column `End Date` like this,

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->renameColumn('Date', 'Start Date');
    $table->dateTime('End Date');
});
```

Comment: new table i already created. i just want to iterate the list of old table and insert it into new table which have start date and end date..

Comment: Why not just change the old table?

Comment: @KrisRoofe - part of the Question is to populate the new column!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO new_table
    (user_id, reason, start_date, end_date)
    SELECT user_id, reason
           MIN(Date), MAX(Date)
        FROM old_table
        GROUP BY user_id, reason;
```

I left out id, assuming that it is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  But it may make more sense to have `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, reason)`.

You did not say that the original rows are 'consecutive', nor did you say that the same user can or cannot have multiple strings of the same `reason`.  So, perhaps I have not solved the real problem.  In which case, edit your Question to be more precise.